# Dev Tools Inspector shows CSS in head, not as external file

Tags: firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I am stumped with Inspector, both Chrome and Firebug, as to why the CSS of the site I am developing locally is inserted into the head of the page. Is this normal? View Source shows that it is externally linked but the inspector converts it to an embedded style sheet. The original href is converted to a data-href attribute. The problem with this is I get no line references for css, everything just refers to the current page! I'm working on a wordpress site through MAMP Pro. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Grr. I just figured it out, it was Prefix-free, which was embedding the style